# Understanding two-button ratings implementation

Tags: sonos

I'm in the midst of implementing two-button ratings on our platform and I'm tearing my hair out on some of the finer details.

Firstly, I've really tried here to explain the trouble I'm having succinctly!

We have three states handled and returned via the `rateItem` and `getExtendedMetadata` endpoints and users can move between the three states:

> 0 - Unrated
>   1 - Up voted
>   2 - Down voted

So `rateItem` accepts one of those three options.

Looking at the [documentation](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/368), my presentation map should be along these lines.

```
 <Match propname="vote" value="0">
  <!-- the track is unrated -->
  <Ratings>
   <Rating AutoSkip="NEVER" Id="1" StringId="VoteUp" OnSuccessStringId="VoteUpSuccess">
    ...
   </Rating>
   <Rating AutoSkip="ALWAYS" Id="0" StringId="VoteDown" OnSuccessStringId="VoteDownSuccess">
    ...
   </Rating>
  </Ratings>
 </Match>
 <Match propname="vote" value="1">
  <!-- the track is rated thumbs up -->
  <Ratings>
   <Rating AutoSkip="NEVER" Id="3" StringId="VoteUp" OnSuccessStringId="VoteUpSuccess">
    ...
   </Rating>
   <Rating AutoSkip="ALWAYS" Id="2" StringId="VoteDown" OnSuccessStringId="VoteDownSuccess">
    ...
   </Rating>
  </Ratings>
 </Match>
 <Match propname="vote" value="2">
  <!-- the track is rated thumbs down -->
  <Ratings>
   <Rating AutoSkip="NEVER" Id="5" StringId="VoteUp" OnSuccessStringId="VoteUpSuccess">
    ...
   </Rating>
   <Rating AutoSkip="ALWAYS" Id="6" StringId="VoteDown" OnSuccessStringId="VoteDownSuccess">
    ...
   </Rating>
  </Ratings>
 </Match>
```

This is where I start to get into trouble. The `<Match ... value="X">` elements appear to be fine and match what my data shows. **But when the buttons are clicked, the `rateItem` endpoint appears to receive IDs 0 through 6.** (ID 4 is missing in the example?)

The documentation states:

> Id (int) This is the value that will be passed to the rateItem method.  The Id must be unique for the given property name.

So, to combat this, I've modified my presentation map so that the IDs sent from the 0 Match property are 1 and 2 (up and down voted). There's then a 1 Match property that links to 0 and 2, and a 2 that links to 0 and 1. Here's where I'm at:

```
 <Match propname="vote" value="0">
  <!-- the track is unrated -->
  <Ratings>
   <Rating AutoSkip="NEVER" Id="1" StringId="VoteUp" OnSuccessStringId="VoteUpSuccess">
    ...
   </Rating>
   <Rating AutoSkip="NEVER" Id="2" StringId="VoteDown" OnSuccessStringId="VoteDownSuccess">
    ...
   </Rating>
  </Ratings>
 </Match>
 <Match propname="vote" value="1">
  <!-- the track is rated thumbs up -->
  <Ratings>
   <Rating AutoSkip="NEVER" Id="0" StringId="VoteUpCancel" OnSuccessStringId="VoteUpCancelSuccess">
    ...
   </Rating>
   <Rating AutoSkip="NEVER" Id="2" StringId="VoteDown" OnSuccessStringId="VoteDownSuccess">
    ...
   </Rating>
  </Ratings>
 </Match>
 <Match propname="vote" value="2">
  <!-- the track is rated thumbs down -->
  <Ratings>
   <Rating AutoSkip="NEVER" Id="1" StringId="VoteUp" OnSuccessStringId="VoteUpSuccess">
    ...
   </Rating>
   <Rating AutoSkip="NEVER" Id="0" StringId="VoteDownCancel" OnSuccessStringId="VoteDownCancelSuccess">
    ...
   </Rating>
  </Ratings>
 </Match>
```

Note the String IDs are updated too and I'm confident my strings file and images are fine.

This makes sense to me, but is really throwing out my images and alerts and I have varying results on different platforms (tested so far on iOS and Mac controllers).

At this point, can anyone offer any suggestions? I'm hoping I've made enough sense here! I'd very much appreciate any tips anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation here on the http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/368, you were right with your first example and the id is what you should be seeing on the rateItem endpoint. The value delineates a more general category (thumbs up, thumbs down, neutral), but the id is the specific state within the category. In your second example, you are repeating id numbers within the same propname which is why you are seeing inconsistent behavior.

In general, the flow should be as follows, when the rateItem request comes in to your service with the unique identifier from the ID this should allow you to rate the track appropriately on the back end. You should respond with a rateItemResponse, that will in turn be followed by a getLastUpdate request (that will update the rating state across all controllers connected to the household), and a getExtendedMetdata request so that the property value can be updated to the one associated with the id that was sent.